# Выборка для шифровального алгоритма

Tags: шифрование, тестирование, выборка, статистика

Приветствую. 
Извиняюсь, если вопрос не совсем по теме сайта.

В общем есть алгоритм шифрования и есть файл который он будет шифровать. Нужно узнать сколько раз зашифровать файл(т.е. протестировать программу), чтобы сказать, что средняя скорость шифрования файла составляет n времени (время мы получим во время теста) с вероятностью 95-99%.
Как это рассчитать?

Есть ли какие-то специальные статистические формулы?

И верно ли я предполагаю, как нужно тестировать?

Answer (score 0):

Сделай наоборот. Шифруй одну (или 10, или 60) минуту подряд, а потом смотри сколько информации успел зашифровать за это время.

Answer (score 0):

Формула простая:

```
    n = L/t

где:

n - скорость шифрования

L - размер файла

t - время шифрования
```

Пример:

Удалось зашифровать 10Gb(10240Mb) за 35 сек

n = 10240 / 35 = 292,57

скорость составила 292,57Mb/s

Comment: Мне кажется. Вы не совсем поняли, что нужно мне. А именно. Количество тестов(шифрований), для получения среднего времени шифрования n. Причем то, что это время действительно примерное время шифрования, должно быть верно на 95%. То есть при других наборах тестов, мне в 95% случаев попадал такой же результат.